# unable to change screen resolution of tty

Tags: linux, virtualbox, console, resolution

I am using Fedora 21 in Oracle Virtual Box. I am using just tty (no GUI). I need to increase screen resolution, I tried following things but failed:

`xrandr` but gives me error: `cannot open display`

I also tried typing `video=1024x768` as kernel parameter but no success

also tried `cvt 1024 768`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `/etc/default/grub` as
`:~$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

add `vga=795` to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, it might look like this:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash vga=792"`

then update grub
`:~$ sudo update-grub`

now reboot
`:~$ sudo reboot -r now`

This method worked for Fedora 21 and Debian 8 in Oracle virtualbox 5

Answer (score 1):

You have to install guest additions...

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/44503/fedora-20-virtualbox-guest-additions-install/